# Key frame is not working

Tags: jquery, css, keyframe

Hi all am trying to create keyframe animation for my top-bar and some boxes but its not working, help me out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/QZnYb/4/)

```
 @-webkit-keyframes flow{

    0% {
        top:-100px;
    }

    100% {
        top: 75px;
    }

}
@keyframes flow{

    0% {
        top:-100px;
    }

    100% {
        top: 75px;
    }

}

.animate-flow{
    -webkit-animation-name: flow;
            animation-name: flow;
}
```

and i add the class while page load using jquery

```
$('.top-bar').addClass('animate-flow');
```

its not working

Comment: so it's defo *not working*? Could you clarify that this is *not working*? ;)

Comment: On a serious note what's a *keyframe animation*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are all the different properties you can use with `keyframes`:

```
animation-name:;
 animation-duration:;
 animation-iteration-count:;
 animation-direction:;
 animation-timing-function:;
 animation-fill-mode:;
 animation-delay:;
```

Change you code

```
.animate-flow{
-webkit-animation-name: flow;
        animation-name: flow;
```

}

to e.g.:

```
.animate-flow{
    -webkit-animation: flow 3s ease-in-out;
            animation: flow 3s ease-in-out;
}
```

[**Updated FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/QZnYb/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.animate-flow{
animation: flow 5s;
-webkit-animation: flow 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZnYb/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add duration to animate-flow and bounce classes like what's shown at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZnYb/8/)

```
 -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZnYb/6/)

What you missed is that you need to give a duration of the animation not just call the animation name.

So a class in your fiddle now looks like this:

```
.animate-flow{
    animation:3s flow;
    -webkit-animation:3s flow;    
}
```

Also don't forget about -moz-, -ms-, -o- too.